# Validation Controls for ASP.NET Server side or client side?

Tags: asp.net, validation, controls

Does the validation controls in ASP.NET works in server side as well as client side? or it is for client side validation only?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ASP.NET validation control perform both `client side` and `server side` validation. `EnableClientValidation` is the property to `disable` client side validation.

Quoted from MSDN Document for [ASP.NET Validation Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kh55542%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> Validation controls perform input checking in server code. When the
>   user submits a page to the server, the validation controls are invoked
>   to check the user input, control by control.  Validation occurs after
>   page initialization (that is, after view state and postback data have
>   been processed) but before any change or click event handlers are
>   called.
>
> ASP.NET performs validation on the server even if the validation
>   controls have already performed it on the client, so that you can test
>   for validity within your server-based event handlers.
>
> You can invoke validation in your own code by calling a validation
>   control's Validate method

Comment: The validation controls can also be used in conjunction with the  `Page.IsValid` property on the server side to validate user input.