# Validation controls in ASP.NET are run at server- or client-side?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating an ASP.NET application and I want to know where are the validation controls on ASP.NET run? On server or on client machine?

Should I consider using JavaScript to perform simple form validations to my project instead?

Comment: Some might run in both, but all should run server-side.  You can consider JavaScript for UX improvements, but any actual validation should be done server-side.  Never implicitly trust data from the client.

Comment: both: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24596891/validation-controls-for-asp-net-server-side-or-client-side

Answer (score 3):

Why not do both? For security purposes you absolutely need to do user input validation in your back end code (C#/ASP.NET), and at the same time it's a better user experience if they get real time validation as they are filling out a form (Angular/JS).

Answer (score 3):

Anything since around ASP.NET 2.0 will run a server side check on the page to make sure it is valid by checking any validator controls (which runs server side) with the .IsValid() in the Form_Load property in the code behind. This process requires a postback to the server which means that if they missed something simple like filling in a name field that they had to submit the form first which is not performant and sometimes expensive.

There is a validator property on the controls entitled 'EnableClientScript' which will run a javascript function to verify simple things like missing field information or even reg ex checks on things like phone number or e-mail address.

David is also correct that you want to verify this input anyway. The best policy is to defensively code against any unintentional or malicious attempts especially if you have a public facing site.