# button cancel doesn't work before I fill all the field (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net

After fill all the fields , submit button doesn't work and cancel also do nothing.

This function in my _.aspx.cs code:

```
     protected void cancel_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");}
```

and this is my aspx code

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DonorSignUp.aspx.cs"> Inherits="BloodBank.DonorSignUp" %>



<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="title" runat="server">

Donor Sign Up Page
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="contentBody" runat="server">
    <
<h1> DONOR REGISTRATION<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnStr %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [donor_table]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </h1>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td> First Name  </td>
            <td> <asp:TextBox ID="name" runat="server" Width="139px"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator12" runat="server" ControlToValidate="name" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
         </td>           
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td> <asp:TextBox ID="last" runat="server" Width="140px"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="last" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
   </td>
        </tr>
            <td>Username</td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="username" runat="server" Width="176px"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator10" runat="server" ControlToValidate="username" ErrorMessage="Please enter the usename"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
   </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="password" runat="server" Width="170px" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator11" runat="server" ControlToValidate="password" ErrorMessage="password"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Confirm</td>
            <td> <asp:TextBox ID="confirm" runat="server" Width="155px" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ControlToCompare="password" ControlToValidate="confirm" ErrorMessage="password doesn't match"></asp:CompareValidator>
    </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><asp:Label ID="msgDSignUp" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Fill all the blanks"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                 <asp:Button ID="SignUpDonor" runat="server" Text="Submit" BackColor="#ff99cc" BorderColor="#ff99cc" OnClick="SignUpDonor_Click1" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="cancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClick="cancel_Click1"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
       </table>   

</asp:Content>
```

When I press cancel button , it does nothing unless I fill all the field in the page ,, if I filled them and press cancel it does the code inside  cancel_Click

Can you help me to manipulate this?

Comment: ValidationGroups are your friend. Or use CausesValidation=false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct behavior. If you want to test it by going straight to the Cancel event handler, then just comment out all the validators or disable client-side validation temporarily using CausesValidation="false". Validation can occur on both client and server - always best to use both.

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582374/validation-controls-in-asp-net-are-run-at-server-or-client-side).

Comment: Thank you I solved my problem by using CausesValidation="false".